# How can I localize the reasons for excessive goal expansion?

Tags: prolog, dcg, sicstus-prolog

The execution profiler of SICStus Prolog 4.5.1 gave me the following output:

```
| ?- print_profile.
       insns   try/retry      called        name
----------------------------------------------------------------
                             4965857/4965857    prolog:wellformed_body_expand/11
   201383839     4965857     4965857        prolog:call_goal_expansion/6
                            *4860319/4860363    prolog:choice/0
                             4860319/9720726    prolog:in_hook_flag/2
                             4860319/9006266    prolog:prolog_catch/3
----------------------------------------------------------------
                             4965868/4965868    prolog:wellformed_body_iso/11
   178771039    19863439     4965868        prolog:wellformed_body_expand/11
                             4965857/4965857    prolog:call_goal_expansion/6
                             4965857/4965857    prolog:goal_exp/8
                             4965857/4965857    prolog:wf_source_module/2
----------------------------------------------------------------
   165399306     5469803     ...
----------------------------------------------------------------
                             3044459/3044459    prolog:dcg_translate_dcg_safe/8
   163441583    23688395     3044459        prolog:dcg_translate_dcg_atom/6
----------------------------------------------------------------
                             ...
```

**Quite puzzling!** It seems that 3/4 of all work (column #1 in the table) is due to goal expansion.

But why? **How can I localize the code causing all these goal expansions?** Please help!

---

#### EDIT: New profiling results

@PerMildner's answer and comments pointed the way to resolving the issue. New execution profiling results of `magic_square__no_sym(4)` (magic squares of size 4x4 with additional constraints between corner points to eliminate symmetric solutions) using `library(clpz)` look *a lot* more reasonable:

```
| ?- print_profile.
       insns   try/retry      called        name
----------------------------------------------------------------
                             1197973/2041757    clpz:fd_put/3
                              843784/2041757    clpz:fd_put/5
   153514528     5339777     2041757        clpz:put_terminating_q/4
                               34012/8145271    clpz:domain_infimum/2
                               34012/8263457    clpz:domain_supremum/2
                                  16/1224480    clpz:new_queue/1
                               51821/51821      clpz:queue_goal_q/2
                              620022/620022     clpz:trigger_props_q/5
----------------------------------------------------------------
                             1197973/1224480    clpz:fd_put/3
                                  16/1224480    clpz:put_terminating_q/4
                               26357/1224480    clpz:trigger_once/1
                                 134/1224480    clpz:variables_same_queue/1
   113876576           0     1224480        clpz:new_queue/1
----------------------------------------------------------------
                             ...
```

The performance impact of the changes in goal expansion for this case are very impressive: **2X** !

Comment: Unlike other systems, SICStus goal expansion is also called when updating dynamic predicates at runtime (IIRC). Could that explain the number of calls you observe?

Comment: @PauloMoura. I ran `| ?- N=4,statistics(runtime,[T0|_]), (magic_square(N,Zss), append(Zss,Zs), labeling([ff],Zs),write(.),false;true), statistics(runtime,[T1|_]), T is T1-T0, write(t=T),nl,!,false.` using `library(clpz)` and the magic square sample code (slightly modified) and a slightly modified version of the library...

Comment: @PauloMoura. Slightly modified for a simple reason. I wanted to see if some of the auxiliary code that the library implementation uses is in fact free with SICStus. E.g.,  `A = A ==> [].` that `(=)/4` can be handy and improve code readability, but is it (almost) free?

Comment: SICStus tries to be clever when there is no goal expansion that can be applicable. In that case the call to `call_goal_expansion` can often be avoided. However, if there is a goal expansion visible (e.g. by loading `clpz`) and that goal expansion has poor indexing, then the full goal expansion processing is attempted. The latter may be what happens because of the "defaulty" [last clause](https://github.com/triska/clpz/blob/cf8db7e807078a4c0692ae0f9d6b3dd249a4da53/clpz.pl#L3066) of `clpz:goal_expansion/5`.

Comment: @PerMildner. Brilliant! Looking forward to trying that out! Please put your comment in an answer so I can accept/upvote/reward it. Nice link, btw. Very useful!

Comment: @PerMildner. I added cuts at the end of each goal_expansion clause, but so far no luck:( Will retry tomorrey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SICStus tries to be clever when there is no goal expansion that can be applicable. In that case the call to `call_goal_expansion` can often be avoided. However, if there is a goal expansion visible (e.g. by loading `clpz`) and that goal expansion has poor indexing, then the full goal expansion processing is attempted. The latter may be what happens because of the "defaulty" [last clause](https://github.com/triska/clpz/blob/cf8db7e807078a4c0692ae0f9d6b3dd249a4da53/clpz.pl#L3066) of `clpz:goal_expansion/5`.

Note that "poor indexing" cannot be worked around by adding cuts in this case. Internally, SICStus looks into the indexing data structure for the `goal_expansion/5` predicate to determine whether any of its clauses could be applicable. A catch-all clause, like the linked one, makes this test fail and the full, slower, `call_goal_expansion` will be called.

Comment: Interesting! How about rewriting (unrolling) that part of the code to individual goal expansion clauses (for `(in)/2`, one for `(#=)/2`, etc.)? (Plus some additional API for retracting these clauses upon library user request...)

Comment: Yes, if the catch-all-clause is really the problem, then replacing it with individual, indexable, clauses, would probably avoid the slow path. That change has to be done in `clpz`, which is not part of SICStus Prolog.